# How to get user input to Stop Python code

Tags: python, python-3.x

So Im making a python programming that automatically moves your mouse indefinitely. I need a way for the user to be able to give a certain input to stop the mouse on  comand. What would i need to add for that to happen. Code below

```
from tracemalloc import stop
from unittest import result
import pyautogui
import time 
import random
while True in range (0,5):
    x = random.randint(0,5)
    y = random.randint(0,5)
    pyautogui.moveTo(x,y)

    localtime = time.localtime()
    result = time.strftime("%I:%M:$S %p", localtime)

    print ('Moveed at ' + str(result) + ' (' + str(x) + ',' + str(y) + ')')
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: `True in range (0,5):` will always be true. `True` is equivalent to `1`, and `1` is always in that range. If you want an infinite loop, just use `while True:`

Comment: You can interrupt execution with ctrl+C, or interrupting the kernel. This first option will generate KeyboardInterrupt

Comment: Yea but i want to add this to a website, and crtl+C only works for me when i use it inside of the terminal. How would stopping it work for somebody who is just using the application

Comment: @Jaedon23 can you explain what you mean by adding a **python** program to a **website**?

Comment: @Harsh I’m just trying to make a simple website that where i’ll have the link to this program so one can run it. As of now I just have the python program and I heard it’s more beneficial to make a web application rather than convert the py file to a .exe file.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like a cross platform solution the following method will work, but it is more verbose than the solution that only works for Windows.

https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#monitoring-the-keyboard

`pip install pynput`

```
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key

KEY_TO_STOP_PROGRAM = Key.f1
run = True

def on_press(key):
    global run
    if key == KEY_TO_STOP_PROGRAM:
        run = False
    # This print statement can be added to see what keys map to what
    # in the pynput module
    print(key)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    listener = keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
    )
    listener.start()

    while run:
        # Your code here

        print("I am running")

    print("program exit")
```

If you are just implementing for Windows the keyboard module should work, but it requires sudo permission for Linux users, and I think because of that, the cross-platform solution is better.

https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/

`pip install keyboard`

```
import keyboard

# Use whatever key you may want
KEY_TO_STOP_PROGRAM = "ctrl + alt"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        # Your code here

        #Check if user inputs key to stop program
        if keyboard.is_pressed(KEY_TO_STOP_PROGRAM):
            # You can also use break
            # But quit() seems to fit your specifications more
            quit()
```